# Using curl with windows path

Tags: bash

I am using `git version 2.17.0.windows.1` and I am trying to install [git-ftp under windows](https://github.com/git-ftp/git-ftp/blob/master/INSTALL.md#windows).

I tried to do the following in my git bash:

```
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/git-ftp/git-ftp/master/git-ftp > C:\Program Files(x86)\Git\bin
```

However, I get the following error:

[image]

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

**1.**

I tried the following:

```
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/git-ftp/git-ftp/master/git-ftp -o "C:\Program Files(x86)\Git\bin"
```

However I receive an error:

[image]

**2.**

I also tried:

```
$ curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/git-ftp/git-ftp/master/git-ftp > "C:\Program Files(x86)\Git\bin"
bash: C:\Program Files(x86)\Git\bin: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Using `(` on the bash command line without quoting it?

Comment: I'd also note that `C:\Program Files(x86)\Git\bin` parses as two arguments, `C:Program` and `Files(x86)Gitbin` (except `(` is a syntax error there).

Comment: @melpomene Thx for your comments. How should correct path look like?

Comment: Your update indicates that you are trying to save the file into place that doesn't exist. Create a directory first and then try to download the file

Comment: `'C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\somefilenamehere'`. Note the quotes and the space before `(`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of redirecting pipe you can save the content to the file using this command:

```
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/git-ftp/git-ftp/master/git-ftp -o "C:\Program Files(x86)\Git\bin"
```

If you prefer to redirect the pipe then you are missing quota:

```
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/git-ftp/git-ftp/master/git-ftp > "C:\Program Files(x86)\Git\bin"
```

Comment: I tried the two suggested solutions. However, I still receive errors. Please have a look at my updated question.

Comment: As I mentioned in the comment to original question: the directory where you are trying to save the file doesn't exist. Create it before downloading the file. Or change the path to place that already exists.

Comment: @gawki The directory does exist on my computer. It is opened in my windows explorer. ;/

Comment: Another problem might be that this is a directory: "C:\Program Files(x86)\Git\bin". Remember that the last part of the path must be a file.

Comment: @Anna.Klee It does not exist. The directory you have open is `Program Files (x86)`, not `Program Files(x86)`.